# gpiozero.exc.PinPWMUnsupported: PWM is not supported on pin GPIO7 (Raspberry Pi 4B)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpiozero

I am working on my first Raspberry Pi project while following a course for creating a line-following robot. [This](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/robotics-with-raspberry-pi/4/todo/97316) is the course. I followed all the instructions and connected the pins as it describes but when I run the code on the Raspberry Pi OS it throws an error:

> gpiozero.exc.PinPWMUnsupported: PWM is not supported on pin GPIO7
> This is the code:

```
from gpiozero import Robot
from time import sleep

my_robot = Robot(left=(7,8), right=(9,10))

my_robot.forward()
sleep(1)
my_robot.stop()
```

I tried to search for solutions and checked the [official documentation](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_exc.html#gpiozero.PinPWMError) but it hasn't been helpful. How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After many checks, it resulted that the GPIO pins and the software were ok. The motors were connected to a L289N Driver Motor module, which *wasn't getting enough power* from the batteries and this was the cause of the error. In case someone has the same or similar hardware connections and faces this issue, **check if the L289N module is powered on (it should turn on the red LED that's on the module)**.

Comment: so you re-charged the battery to full and this made it started to work again? I just got this issue as well.

Comment: @Franva i had 2 AA batteries and I added 2 more to increase the voltage... after that I was able to see the red light

Comment: thanks @youHaveAIsoBeenABeginner, I charged my battery and then it started to work :)

Answer (score 3):

The likely reason for this error is that the user has installed gpiozero into a virtual environment without installing a pin library. gpiozero's built-in pin interface does not support PWM. You need to install RPi.GPIO to get the normal experience:

```
pip install gpiozero rpi-gpio
```

This is mentioned in the docs: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-do-i-get-pinfactoryfallback-warnings-when-i-import-gpiozero

Comment: this! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with gpiozero's CamJamKitRobot and Robot classes when trying to run it in a pipenv (same issue may occur with a virtual env, but I have not tried). Running the script outside of the pipenv (therefore just using the system installed pip packages) resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I was following the guide on https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2018/02/basic-servo-use-with-the-raspberry-pi/ with Micro Servo WS-SG90 and Raspberry Pi 3B+ and used the `gpiozero` Python library and ran into the same exception. In my case this was caused by running the program as non-root user. Running the program with `sudo` made the servo turn. The other alternative would be to use `PiGPIOFactory` with `pigpiod` which does not require to run the program with elevated privileges.